# Find function which a stable manifold of equilibrium point of dynamical system is tangent to

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

I have the system
$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x}\\\dot{y} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \sin{x} - 2y\\ 2x+2y
\end{bmatrix}$$
I have to prove that the stable manifold associated with the equilibrium point at origin is tangent to $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$.

So far I've linearized the system to get $A = Df(0)= \begin{bmatrix} -3 & -2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors $\lambda=1,-2$, with $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

I'm unsure what to do next - am I supposed to solve the system? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No, it does not mean that the stable subspace is the $x$-axis. You need eigenvectors for conclusions of this kind.

Comment: @Artem I was a bit too fast on that one! I've updated the question

Comment: Your stable manifold has the property that the eigenvector, which corresponds to the negative eigenvalue, is tangent to it. Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the stable and unstable subspace of the linear system:
$$E^s = \text{Span}\{v_2\}, \quad E^u = \text{Span}\{v_1\}$$

From the Stable Manifold Theorem, we know that the stable manifold S is tangent to the stable subspace $E^s$ of the linear system at origin.

$v_1$ can be described as the line $y=-\frac{1}{2}$